# Glassfish failed start on update

Tags: glassfish

I'm new to ServerFault. My problem is that recently(today) the Update Tool Notifier of glassfish executed an update. Everything seemed to go well but when I tried to start the server, it threw this error

> Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
>   ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.osgi-http [258]: Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/modules/autostart/osgi-http.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle org.glassfish.osgi-http [258].)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.glassfish.internal.api.Globals.get(Globals.java:73)
>           at org.glassfish.osgihttp.Activator.getStandardContext(Activator.java:97)
>           at org.glassfish.osgihttp.Activator.start(Activator.java:89)
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:629)
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1835)
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1752)
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1156)
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

I don't know how to fix this, please help me.